# react native MaterialTopTabNavigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to implement this code to my TopTabNavigator:

```
    const tabNavigator = createMaterialTopTabNavigator({ /* */ });
tabNavigator.navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
  let activeRoute = navigation.state.routes[navigation.state.index];
  if (activeRoute.routeName === 'Offers') { // or whatever the name is
    return {
      headerRight: <SomeThingHere />
    };
  } else {
    return {};
  }
};
```

This is the code I have so far:

```
    const TopTab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();

function MyOffersTabNavigation() {
  const {theme} = useTheme();
  return (
    <TopTab.Navigator
      tabBarOptions={{
        labelStyle: {
          fontFamily: boldFont,
          fontSize: 15,
          textTransform: 'none',
          paddingVertical: 6,
        },
        activeTintColor: theme.topTab.topTabActiveColor,
        inactiveTintColor: theme.topTab.topTabInactiveColor,
        indicatorStyle: {
          backgroundColor: theme.topTab.topTabIndicatorColor,
          height: 2,
          bottom: -1,
        },
        style: {
          borderBottomWidth: 1,
          borderBottomColor: theme.borderColor,
          backgroundColor: theme.topTab.topTabBgColor,
          borderTopLeftRadius: 30,
          borderTopRightRadius: 30,
        },
      }}
      style={{
        // backgroundColor: colorScheme === 'dark' ? '#1D2633' : mainBackgroundColor,
        backgroundColor: theme.header.backgroundColor,
        paddingTop: 10,
      }}
      screenOptions={({navigation, route}) => {
        if (route.name === 'Offers' && navigation.isFocused()) {
          isActive = true; 
          if(Platform.OS === 'ios') {
            isActive = false; 
          }
        } else if (route.name !== 'Offers' && navigation.isFocused()) {
          isActive = false;  
          if(Platform.OS === 'ios') {
            isActive = true; 
          }    
        }
      }}
      barStyle={{backgroundColor: mainBackgroundColor, paddingTop: 20}}>
      <TopTab.Screen name="Offers" component={MyOffersView}  />
      <TopTab.Screen name="Offer Lists" component={MyOffersListView} />
    </TopTab.Navigator>
  );
}
```

Any ideas how to do this? I want to use navigationOptions in hope I can get active route of one specific tab, so I can show an Icon in header. Basically, the idea is to show icon in header only when the first (Offers) tab is active, so I figured I could create custom header for my top tabs and if first tab is active, show custom header with that icon. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

just add options prop to Tab's Screen where you need Icon when tab is active

```
<TopTab.Screen 
    name="Offers"
    component={MyOffersView} 
    options={{
        headerRight: () => (
            <SomeComponentHere />
        )
    }}
/>
```